# Cannot open .sdf files in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 SP3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Has made a .sdf database file in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010. When I try to open it in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Service Pack 3, it displays error message:

> Cannot connect to C:\Users\Xtreme\Documents\Dishes.sdf.
>
> Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run
>   repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version =
>   4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name =
>   \?\C:\Users\Xtreme\Documents\Dishes.sdf ] (SQL Server Compact ADO.NET
>   Data Provider)

What is wrong? There is no problem to work with the .sdf in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Erik EJ's web log](http://erikej.blogspot.com/) - he has a ton of tools for handling all sorts of operations with `.sdf` files, and also an extensive list of third-party tools that work with SQL Server Compact Edition's `.sdf` files.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use SSMS to open SQL CE 4.0 Database files.

You can use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer to load VS Tools for SQL CE 4 however.

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/a9fca12d-6403-47ff-ab6b-fc1db42205c3

WebMatrix should be able to view/edit these database files as well.

Comment: I also suggest you this [application](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/Database-NET.shtml). Also you can use [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/) addon for visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open SQL Server Management Studio, or if it's running select File -> Connect Object Explorer...
   2.In the Connect to Server dialog change Server type to SQL Server Compact Edition
    From the Database file dropdown select
   3. Open your SDF file.

Comment: Does not work for me. De sdf opened once in 2008! Reading, qry, everything. After that it would not open any more. Same file, same MStudio. Replaced file, no results. Crazy. Message DBVersion=0, RequestedVersion=0. Very strange and frustrating. It's eating hours and hours already.